# Even Listener for .length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I have a script that counts the amount of classes in the document, however, I'm using another jquery script to '.remove' the classes when clicked, but the .alerts count remains the same. I'm assuming this is because the document needs an event listener but can't seem to get it working.

html -

```
 <ul>
 <li class="alert"> </li>
 <li class="alert"> </li>
 <li class="alert"> </li>
 </ul>

<div class="counter">3</div>

 document.getElementsByClassName("counter")[0].textContent
 =document.querySelectorAll("ul > .alert").length;
```

It displays the correct amount, but doesn't change when they're removed by jquery, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need either a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or a custom `.remove` function that changes it every time it is called (Or just overwrite JQuery's one to execute the old one and then change the counter)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is non-live, if you use `getElementsByClassName` it's a live collection, and the length does update, but you have to refresh the DOM as well -> https://jsfiddle.net/xneLogp1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function which updates current `.length` of elements when element is removed

```js
$(function() {

  function count() {
    $(".counter").html($(".alert").length)
  }

  count();

  $(".alert").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    count();
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".alert").eq(+$(this).prev("input").val()).remove();
    $(this).prev("input").attr("max", $(".alert").length)
    .val($(".alert").length -1)
    count()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="alert">click</li>
  <li class="alert">click</li>
  <li class="alert">click</li>
</ul>

<div class="counter"></div>
<input type="number" min="0" max="2" value="2">
<button>remove alert</button>
```

Comment: This is perfect, can't believe how simple it is, feel like I was over complicating it in hindsight. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe modifications to the DOM. See example below:

```js
function updateCount() {
  $(".counter").eq(0).html($("ul > .alert").length);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    updateCount();
    // ...
  });
  var ul = $('#alertList');
  // define what element should be observed by the observer
  // and what types of mutations trigger the callback
  observer.observe(document.getElementById('alertList'), {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    childList: true
      //...
  });
});
$('#addLi').click(function() {
  $('#alertList').append('<li class="alert"></li>');
});
//allow removing items by clicking on them
$('.alert').click(function(event) {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="alertList">
  <li class="alert"></li>
  <li class="alert"></li>
  <li class="alert"></li>
</ul>

<button id="addLi">Add Item</button>
<div class="counter">3</div>
```